# JAVA: How can I sort an array by its next nearest value?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, numbers, closest

I am kind of new to java. I have seen the algorithms for sorting number in ascending/descending order, where the first entry is smallest/biggest. I have never seen the an algorithm that can sort element to its nearest value keeping first entry unchanged.

For example:
array= **53, 98, 183, 37, 122, 14, 124, 65, 67**

and return this:

array= **53, 65, 67, 37, 14, 98, 122, 124, 183**

Just to explain the example little better, please note that in output, first entry `53` is unchanged. Next entry is `65` which is closest of all remaining entries with minimum difference of `12`. After `65`, its `67` which has difference of `2` among the remaining entries (excluding `53` and `65`). Same way, next entry is `37` which is closest to `67` among the remaining entries.

***Any help is appreciated!!!***

Comment: Your requirements are not clear.  At first I thought you were sorting by differences, but that's not the case.  Can you explain the desired results more clearly?  What does "closer" mean in this context?

Comment: Do you start with first element in the array or largest in the array? If you are starting with largest in the array, your are sorting in descending order.

Comment: I think he starts with first...53 is larger than 37. He's (I think) asking how to sort all the numbers by ascending order...wait..."67 is closer to 37" ???

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. The first element is anchored and stays put at array[0].  For n>0 you choose the element at x such that abs(a[x]-a[n-1]) is minimal, and repeat until you've chosen all elements.

Comment: The standard question: What have you tried?  And: This probably belongs on [programmers.se] since it's more of an algorithm question than a coding question.

Comment: Take a look at [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode, untested:

```
for i in 0..array.length-1
{
  min=MAX_INT
  minIndex=0
  for j in i+1..array.length-1
  {
    diff=abs(a[j]-a[i])
    if diff < min
    {
      min = diff
      minIndex=j
    }
  }
  swap a[i+1] with a[minIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
    int[] array = new int[] {53, 98, 183, 37, 122, 14, 124, 65, 67};

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int currentValue = array[i];
        int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int j = i+1; j < array.length ; j++) {
            if(Math.abs(array[j] - currentValue) < distance ) {
                distance = Math.abs(array[j] - currentValue);
                int temp = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output `53 65 67 37 14 98 122 124 183`